# How to set the default debug memory view rendering and cell size in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to set the default memory view rendering and a default cell size (for Traditional rendering) in Eclipse? Currently the default behavior for each new added memory location is Hex rendering and 4-byte cell size. I couldn't find an option to change this through GUI. Is it possible to change this at all i.e. by modifying preferences manually or so?

[image: memory view]

Comment: This is not part of core Eclipse, what is it?

Comment: I think it comes with CDT, added a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can archive this by modifying CDT plugin source code, and then re-build CDT and reinstall it.

In fact, I am developing an MCU IDE based Eclipse, so I modify CDT source code sometimes.For your question, I modified the code like this and worked:

```
public Control createControl(Composite parent)
{
    allocateColors();

    this.fRendering = new RenderingAddressInfo(parent, this);
    **this.fRendering.setColumnsSetting(4);** //I modified this, and workd!
    applyPreferences();

    createMenus();

    return this.fRendering;
}
```

Above code is from: 
CDT_9_3_0\memory\org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.traditional\src\org\eclipse\cdt\debug\ui\memory\traditional\TraditionalRendering.java

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, I might actually do that considering I already modify another part of CDT. Too bad it's not a GUI option though.